# Implementing a linked list containing all the nodes of each depth of a binary search tree

Tags: c#, linked-list, binary-search-tree

I am to solve on of the cracking the coding interview questions
"Given a binary search tree, design an algorithm which creates a linked list of all the nodes at each depth (i.e., if you have a tree with depth D, you’ll have D linked lists)."

I am curious as to how i would go about implementing a linked list to show the depths for the current code i have been working on??

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BinarySearchTree bst = new BinarySearchTree();
        object[] arr = { 50, 30, 55, 25, 35, 52, 60, 10, 32, 37, 65, 15 };
        bst.AddRange(arr);

        int level = 1;
        string nodeValues = FindNodeValuesAtLevel(bst.Root, level);
        Console.WriteLine("Nodes at level " + level + ": " + nodeValues);


        Console.Read();
    }
    static string FindNodeValuesAtLevel(BSTNode root, int level)
    {
        StringBuilder nodeValuesAtLevel = new StringBuilder();
        RM_FindNodeValuesAtLevel(root, level, 0, nodeValuesAtLevel);
        return nodeValuesAtLevel.ToString();
    }

    static void RM_FindNodeValuesAtLevel(BSTNode node, int targetLevel, int curLevel, StringBuilder itemsAtLevel)
    {

        if (node == null) // stopping condition
            return;
        else // recursive step
        {
            // get node value at the target level
            if (curLevel == targetLevel)
            {
                itemsAtLevel.Append(node.NodeValue + " ");
            }

            // traverse the left node at the next level
            RM_FindNodeValuesAtLevel(node.Left, targetLevel, curLevel + 1, itemsAtLevel);
            // traverse the right node at the next level
            RM_FindNodeValuesAtLevel(node.Right, targetLevel, curLevel + 1, itemsAtLevel);

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here’s an idea:

Walk through the tree in-order. Since you know when you descend into a child tree, you can simply keep track of the height of each node you are visiting. For each node at height `k` you visit, add it to the linked list `k`. If you don’t have a linked list for the height `k` yet, create an empty one and add it to the list/array of linked lists.